# C++ : Get a child member from the Father class

Tags: c++

I recently asked a question related to the accessibility of a child member from a parent class using the cout method . But this time what if I want to use a get method instead of cout ? Will this change the idea  ?
Assuming I have a class called CArray :

```
class CArray
{
 public:
  CArray(); 
  
 private:
  std::vector<CPerson *>Persons;  
};
```

Where CPerson a parent class :

```
class CPerson
{
public:
  CPerson();
  virtual void Print()
    {
        std::cout << Name << "\n";
    }

protected:
  std::string Name;
};
```

and CStudent the child of Person

```
class CStudent : public CPerson
{
public:
  CStudent();

private:
  int MatriculationNr;
};
```

Let's assume that  we loaded the private members of CStudent and CPerson as follows :

```
if (condition)
  {
    CStudent *S1 = new CStudent();
    S1->load(src); //Load function is missing in class but ignore it 
    Persons.push_back(S1);
  }
```

I recently learned how to access the private member of CStudent and CPerson with the use of the virtual method and exactly by adding to `CStudent class` this function below :

```
void Print()
    {
        CPerson::Print();
        std::cout << MatriculationNr << "\n";
    }
```

Now moving on to my class  `CArray` . I wrote a print method to print the elements of `Persons` :
I just have to write `Persons[i]->Print();` which will call Print() from all `Persons` .
The question now what If I want to get the `MatriculationNr` from the first element of Persons (as an example)?
`cout << Persons[i]->getMatrikulNr();`is not valid since we're trying here to get a function from a child class which is not possible this way .
I wanted to apply the same behavior that I did with print() but this is not possible due to the return parameter that I will have with the get method .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what If I want to get the `MatriculationNr` from the first element of `Persons` (as an example)?

You won't be able to.  Not with the code you have shown, anyway.  `MatriculationNr` exists only in `CStudent`, and it is `private` at that, so only `CStudent` can access it.

> `cout << Persons[i]->getMatrikulNr();` is not valid since we're trying here to get a function from a child class which is not possible this way . I wanted to apply the same behavior that I did with print() but this is not possible due to the return paramater that I will have with the get method .

You would have to either:

- add a public virtual `getMatrikulNr()` method to `CPerson` which `CStudent` can then override, eg:

  ```cpp
  class CPerson
  {
  public:
     ...
     virtual int getMatrikulNr() const
       {
           return 0;
       }
     ...
  };

  class CStudent : public CPerson
  {
  public:
     ...
     int getMatrikulNr() const override
       {
           return MatriculationNr;
       }

  private:
     int MatriculationNr;
  };
  ```

  And then you can use `Persons[i]->getMatrikulNr()` as needed.
- add a public `getMatrikulNr()` method to `CStudent`, and then `dynamic_cast` each `CPerson*` pointer to see if it is pointing at a `CStudent` object or not, eg:

  ```cpp
  class CStudent : public CPerson
  {
  public:
     ...
     int getMatrikulNr() const
       {
           return MatriculationNr;
       }

  private:
     int MatriculationNr;
  };
  ```

  ```cpp
  CStudent *student = dynamic_cast<CStudent*>(Persons[i]);
  if (student) {
       // use student->getMatrikulNr() as needed...
  }
  ```